# Can air be implemented in 1-Dimensional photonic crystals?

Tags: optics, material-science, fiber-optics, photonics

As far as I am aware, digging holes in nanostructures or using columns of materials in a medium of air is the main way by which 2D photonic crystals work. I thought it would also be common to implement air as a layer in 1D photonic crystals but found no clue such a thing exists. Is it possible to do that or does it already exist? If not, why not?

Comment: apparently 1D photonic crystal nanocavities and microcavities exist

Answer (score 0):

Kinda what you're looking for:

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41566-023-01304-y

https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.13.011006

Not photonic crystals yet, but I think you can employ the same idea to make a 1D PhC in air